# How format and re-install new OS on Sony VAIO

Tags: windows-8, formatting, sony-vaio

I bought a new Sony VAIO SVE17135CXB and I want to format the whole drive, set up partitions and install clean OS. But i have couple of questions before I do that:

1. Do I have to do this like I would on a normal PC? Boot Windows from DVD/USB and do all the stuff from there?
2. There is some space reserved for a recovery image. Can I format that as well?
3. Will the "assist" button work after re-installing or do I have to fix it afterwards?
4. In the app menu I have a column called "VAIO APPS". Can I still have that column? (one named with "VAIO APPS")
5. Do I have to re-install all VAIO-only related features or they will be ready with the new OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes
2. yes, but than you cannot recover your computer from this partition
3. can you explain it? if you're talking about additional keys such as multimedia probably you have to install additional software
4. no, you can't
5. I don't understand, could you explain?

Comment: for 3 and 5 i'm reffreing to this guy 
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Qdp3R2WDrOI/ThW_svNiwpI/AAAAAAAAFfg/n4cwzhYGnqA/s640/laptop.jpg
 with on/off button laptop boots normally but with it, it goes to boot up like menu from where you can accsess bios, recovery tools and stuff like that
so back to the question. will this button work after re-install?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea :/

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'm gonna try and hope everything will work afterwards ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Many laptops comes with a preinstalled recovery partition, wich contains format tools, utility and so on.

I suggest you to proceed with the included format utility as it will reinstall all the out-of-the-box software you had at first time.

If you proceed installing a new OS like you would do with a normal pc just don't format the recovery partition.

Comment: Already did, formatted everything. Only thing that does not work is sony vaio special button "VAIO", which should bring up vaio care utility. Everything else works perfect. I'm gonna fix it as soon I get time

Comment: @user2614823 You need to install drivers for VAIO from their website. One of the drivers will be the care utility. I wouldn't install it myself, just the sound, graphics, and memory card drivers etc

Answer (score -1):

there is no need to download the drivers from the website.                       Before formatting your vaio go to C drive and then to the windows folder.you will find a folder named 'Drivers' .copy that folder to any of your mechanical drive ,for example E drive. Thereafter you go for formatting your vaio pc.                         But unfortunately you will not have the studio drivers like acid music studio 9 etc.

Comment: **Don't** do that. Entire point of reinstalling is to start from the beginning. With this method you're moving all old unnecessary stuff from the old OS, including unwanted junk files and outdated drivers. And you can break some drivers if they need additional software. Moving files between two OS installs is a very bad idea in most cases.

Comment: This is not a valid option. The drivers for the computer will most likely be on a recovery partition or recovery CD. You will need the installation drivers, not the artifacts of installed drivers. Additionally, program drivers are packaged with programs.